# Stripes framework unit testing: MockServletContext giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, testng, stripes

EDIT: You can ignore most of what I have written below:

I am getting a null value of context when I do the following in some TestNG code:

```
 public void setupNonTrivialObjects() {
     TestFixture.context = new MockServletContext("test");
     }
```

Am I supposed to do something more to make a MockServletContext object that is not null?

---

ORIGINAL: I am learning to use the Stripes Framework with TestNG.

I am following the example here (but adapting it to my own code): http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Unit+Testing under the heading **Approach 2**

I have this test:

```
public class SeedSearchActionBeanTest {
@Test
public void seedSearchTest() throws Exception {
    // Setup the servlet engine
    MockServletContext ctx = TestFixture.getServletContext();

    MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(ctx, SeedSearchActionBean.class);
    trip.setParameter("input", "sdfs");
    trip.execute();

    SeedSearchActionBean bean = trip.getActionBean(SeedSearchActionBean.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(bean.getInput(),"sdfs");
    Assert.assertEquals(trip.getDestination(), "/results.jsp");
    }
}
```

This "TestFixture" not really sure what that is.

```
public class TestFixture {
 private static MockServletContext context;
 @BeforeSuite
 public void setupNonTrivialObjects() {
     TestFixture.context = new MockServletContext("test"); 
         // Add the Stripes Filter
     Map<String,String> filterParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
     filterParams.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "net.sourceforge.stripes");
     context.addFilter(StripesFilter.class, "StripesFilter", filterParams);
     // Add the Stripes Dispatcher
     context.setServlet(DispatcherServlet.class, "StripesDispatcher", null);
 }

 public static MockServletContext getServletContext() {
     return TestFixture.context;
     }
}
```

I get this error

`FAILED: seedSearchTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockRoundtrip.getUrlBindingStub(MockRoundtrip.java:384)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockRoundtrip.<init>(MockRoundtrip.java:96)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.mock.MockRoundtrip.<init>(MockRoundtrip.java:82)
    at sempedia.tests.action.SeedSearchActionBeanTest.seedSearchTest(SeedSearchActionBeanTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`

I guess this line `MockServletContext ctx = TestFixture.getServletContext();` is not working, I am wondering if there is something I am missing, particularly, is there something I have to do in the web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is with this line:

```
 filterParams.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "net.sourceforge.stripes");`
```

This should be (in my case):

```
filterParams.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "action");
```

Essentially you are setting the package name where the ActionBeans are found. It seems very obvious once you know it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be testing whether you've set up Stripes action bean creation and parameter passing which no doubt have been tested extensively by those developing the Stripes Framework. I tend to test the load/save/etc business logic (services) called from my actions.

Comment: You're right, I was testing the testing, to see how it works.